# How do I write a while loop that iterates through number of hours to find caffeine absorption?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

After caffeine is absorbed into the body, 13% is eliminated
from the body each hour. Assume a person drinks an 8-oz cup of brewed coffee containing 130 mg of caffeine, and that the caffeine is absorbed immediately into the body.

I am writing a program to calculate the following values:

a) The number of hours required until less than 65 mg (one-half the original amount) remain in the body.

b) Suppose the person drinks a cup of coffee at 7 a.m. and then drinks a cup of coffee at the end of each hour until 7 a.m. the next day. How much caffeine will be in the body at the end of the 24 hours?

Here is my code:

```
hour = 0
in_body = 130
while in_body == 65:
    hour -= 0.13*in_body
    hour +=1
```

Why will this not work for a and how do I form the condition statement for b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_body` never changes from 130, so your while loop never executes. Try something like:

```
hours = 0
caffeine = 130
while caffeine > 65:
    caffeine *= 0.87
    hours +=1

print(f'{caffeine} mg of caffeine in body after {hours} hours')
# 64.794719691 mg of caffeine in body after 5 hours
```

You could use a for loop to get the caffeine in the body after 24 hours assuming a cup is consumed each hour. For example:

```
hours = 24
caffeine = 0
for _ in range(hours):
    caffeine = caffeine * 0.87 + 130

print(f'{caffeine} mg of caffeine in body after {hours} hours')
# 964.6440864884751 mg of caffeine in body after 24 hours
```

Comment: Thanks @benvc and any idea how to solve b) Suppose the person drinks a cup of coffee at 7 a.m. and then drinks a cup of coffee at the end of each hour until 7 a.m. the next day. How much caffeine will be in the body at the end of the 24 hours?

Comment: @codeybanks - you could use a for loop for the second problem. See answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't work because `in_body` is 130, therefore it is not equal to 65, and the while loop never executes.

Also, the body of the loop reduces `hour` by 13 percent, but that's wrong -- you want to reduce `in_body`, not `hour`.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
hour = 0
in_body = 130
while in_body > 65:
    in_body = in_body * 0.87
    hour +=1

print('After %d hours, %d mgs of caffeine remain in the body' % (hour, in_body))
```

Comment: Thanks @john and any idea how to solve b) Suppose the person drinks a cup of coffee at 7 a.m. and then drinks a cup of coffee at the end of each hour until 7 a.m. the next day. How much caffeine will be in the body at the end of the 24 hours?

Comment: The loop would be similar, except the condition would be `while hour < 24` and inside the loop you would add 130 to in_body.